# Migrate Oracle v19 SQL Script To MySql v5.7 While Loop Read Schema

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

I would like to convert the following Oracle v19 sql script, to a MySql v5.7 sql script, not as a stored procedure.

Is this possible ?

```
SET serveroutput ON;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1

DECLARE
    v_user_exists INT := 0;
    v_attempts INT := 30;
    v_current_attempt INT := 0;
    e_read_schema_failed EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA exception_init( e_read_schema_failed, -20002 );

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checking for Schema');

    WHILE v_current_attempt < v_attempts
    LOOP
        v_current_attempt := v_current_attempt + 1;
        SELECT count (*)
        INTO v_user_exists
        FROM sys.all_users
        WHERE username = 'ADMIN';

        IF v_user_exists > 0 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Count '||TO_CHAR(v_current_attempt)||' : Schema Found');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Count '||TO_CHAR(v_current_attempt)||' : Schema Not Found');
--            RAISE e_read_schema_failed;
        END IF;

        dbms_lock.sleep(1);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

In turn the above script is invoked in Bash using

```
echo @${READ_SCHEMA_SCRIPT} | sql -S ${USER}/${PASSWORD}@${TNS_NAME}
```

## Solution

Thanks for the suggestions, the final working script is

```
DELIMITER // 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mydb.proc_loop_test//

CREATE PROCEDURE mydb.proc_loop_test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_user_exists INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_attempts INT DEFAULT 30;
    DECLARE v_current_attempt INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_tmp INT DEFAULT 0;
    BEGIN
        WHILE v_int_val < 10 DO
            SET v_int_val=v_int_val+1;

            SELECT COUNT(*)
            INTO @v_user_exists
            FROM information_schema.schemata
            WHERE schema_name = 'mydb';

            IF @v_user_exists > 0 THEN
                SELECT concat('Count ',v_int_val,' : Schema Found');
            ELSE
                SELECT concat('Count ',v_int_val,' : Schema Not Found');
            END IF;

            SELECT SLEEP(1)
            INTO @v_tmp;
        END WHILE;
    END;
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL mydb.proc_loop_test();
```

And the above is the invoked in Bash using

```
mysql -sN -h ${HOST} -u ${USER} -p${PASSWORD} -D ${DBNAME} < ${READ_SCHEMA_SCRIPT})
```

Comment: not sure why this is tagged with `bash`; this looks to be an issue of converting between different SQL dialects

Comment: I'm no mysql expert, but reading from [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-while-loop/) it doesn't seem that complicated

Comment: I don't think you can use `LOOP` and `IF` outside stored procedures in MySQL.